# Modelling Functionalities as Entities in the Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

From my understanding of the DDD concepts, all application functionalities related to an entity should be placed into that entity.
For example: a `UserEntity` should have `register()` for the registration functionality.

However, this does not make sense for a large application where there is a huge number of functionalities. This would mean that one `UserEntity` class will be HUGE since it must have at least one method for each functionality.

I would think the better way is to abstract `register()` into its own entity: a `RegFuncEntity`.
This means each functionality (e.g. registration, login, search users, view membership, pay bills, etc) is abstracted into its own entity. The `UserEntity` still has methods, but only those related to the `User` basic functions (e.g. `updateAddress()`, `updateFirstName()`, `updateSSN()`, `validate()`, etc). The `reRegFuncEntity` can use `UserEntity` (i.e. a functionality entity can use this "core" entities).

My question is: is this design anemic and/or still follow DDD?

Comment: DDD makes provision for the notion of services. If the behaviour doesn't sensibly belong with an entity, it's probably a service.

Answer (score 4):

Domain Driven Design provides you a great tool known as `bounded context`. Your user will do different things in different bounded contexts. For instance: the `User` in the `User Management` BC will have `login()`, `changePassword()` and `User` entity will probably be the Aggregate Root.

In another BC, say `Order`, the `User` entity will provide other functionalities, and in this BC, `User` could not be the aggregate root (indeed, I'll tell you more: it could be a value object).

Then, you will have a one `User` entity for each BC. In DDD the same word could have different meanings (and behaviour) in different context (this is known as Ubiquitous language). The usual example in DDD is the `Order` entity: this means something to forward for the carrier, something to bill for the administrative and so on.
UL is even useful to spot different bounded context, if domain experts use the same word to talk about different things you've probably spotted a new BC.

Another tip of UL is: talk the language of domain experts: than don't use `UserEntity`for users, but simply `User`, non programmer staff will have difficult to catch the meaning of entity.

After this process, if you have some functionality shared among multiple bounded context, you can look at a Shared Kernel.

Comment: Does that mean there is only one UserEntity class for all those contexts? if so, my point was I will have a HUGE UserEntity class since the same class needs to provide at least one method for each bounded context (i.e. login() to login, etc).

Comment: Yes, one (for each BC), if it turns that each User (even in different BC) have the same behaviour or the class is bloated you have a modeling problem. In my experience each entity is relatively small. Take a look at updated answer.

Comment: I see... does that mean codes (e.g. validate() methods, etc) that are common to the User entity in all bounded contexts should be implemented as a UserBase (User 's base class) in the Share Kernel?. Also, your tip in the UL: I won't use the UserEntity to talk to the domain experts, but how about the class name? I saw some ddd examples that have a class name with "Entity" at the end of it (e.g. UserEntity).

Comment: Yes. Clearly the shared kernel need to be really stable, otherwise is a pain in the neck. As far as I can I prefear repeat myself rather than share a kernel. If you have good unit test, code duplication shouldn't a problem.
For the UL: i'm italian and in my project we have started to use italian class name. I.e. call the class as you want, but have in mind to reduce friction, and have in mind continuos refactoring if previous name could be misleading ;)

Comment: mm..I re-read the Chapter 14 of the Eric Evan's book. One bounded context might span multiple modules. From your experience how often a module maps to a bounded context?

Comment: In our case we have nullified the overlapping of bounded context. This is an ideal condition, not always practicable, depends on your use case. :)

Comment: My question probably was not clear enough for you :). I was wondering how often each bounded context maps to a module (e.g. java package) from your experience?

Comment: In my experience: everytime.